# What happens in memory when calling a function with literal values?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an arbitrary function:

```
void someFunc(int, double, char);
```

and I call `someFunc(8, 2.4, 'a');`, what actually happens? How does 8, 2.4, and 'a' get memory, moved into that memory, and passed into the function? What type of optimizations does the compiler have for situations like these? What if I mix and match parameters, such like `someFunc(myIntVar, 2.4, someChar);`?

What happens if the function is declared as `inline`?

Comment: Have a look at the disassembly and find out for yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no difference that the values are literal or not (unless the function is inlined and then the compiler can optimize some stuff out).

Usually, parameters are put into registers or the function parameter stack. Regardless of whether they are explicit values or variables.

**Without optimizations**, the parameter gets pushed onto the parameter stack. In the first case, the value of `x` is taken first and put into register `eax`, then pushed into the parameter stack. `foo` prints `x`.

```
    foo(x);
00361A75  mov         eax,dword ptr [x] 
00361A78  push        eax  
00361A79  call        get_4 (3612B7h) 
00361A7E  add         esp,4 
    foo(3);
00361A81  push        3    
00361A83  call        get_4 (3612B7h) 
00361A88  add         esp,4
```

**With optimizations** the function is visible to the compiler (in my sample) and the call is skipped altogether:

```
    foo(x);
01011000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (101203Ch)] 
01011006  push        3    
01011008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (1012038h)] 
    foo(3);
0101100E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (101203Ch)] 
01011014  push        3    
01011016  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (1012038h)]
```

`foo` is defined as:

```
void foo(int x)
{
   std::cout << x;
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck sure, just a `cout` :)

Comment: @Robᵩ: It appears to be passing a `3` to the function `get_4`.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally* C++ functions work on the stack. I'll describe the [C calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) as it works without optimizations:

It will put `'a'` on top of the stack. Then it puts `2.4` on top of the stack, then it puts `8` on top of the stack, then it adds space for the return type<sup>[1]</sup>, then the instruction pointer of the current instruction in the calling function, and then jumps to the beginning of the called function's code.
The called function will look at the stack, grab the parameters, do it's thing, put the result in the space provided on the stack, and finally jump to the instruction pointed at on the stack (which is presumably the next instruction of the function that called it). Now that the processor is executing the calling function again, it will then copy the result wherever it wants it, and pop all the other stuff off the stack.*

There are [other calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall) (many of which will keep parameters in registers) to save time, and of course, there's other complications due to exceptions.  Depending on the calling function, it may inline the call, which skips all of the steps listed and just executes the called function with those constants directly, or in a *very* advanced compiler and in certain conditions, it might create a copy of the function that has those parameters hardcoded in, and call that version instead parameterless.

As I said, this is all theory I learned years ago.  [Luchian Grigore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988391/845092) has lots of neat details.

<sup>[1] Wikipedia informed me that if the result is a single `int`, it's returned in a register instead of the stack.</sup>